# In Postgres search for multiple words which are partially present in a string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm implementing a rudimentary form of the search. I would like to find all products names that contain all words partially in a search query.

So if I have these two products:

- Deodorant with a cucumber flavor
- Deodorant with apple flavor

I want each individual word in the list of words to be partially present in the string. If any word is not present partially I should discard that row.

the search query: cucumb deod should match only Deoderant with a cucumber flavor.

Comment: Please add only one tag for the **real** Postgres version you are using

Answer (score 1):

You have to split the words in your search string and combine them in your query so that in result it looks like this:

```
... where name like '%cucumb%' and name like '%deod%' ...
```

Of course, in your code you would create a parameterized query, e.g.:

```
... where name like ? and name like ? ...
```

and set the parameters' values accordingly ('%cucumb%' and '%deod%' in the example), depending on the language / API / framework used.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in a single like statement

Comment: Yes, but for your use case that wouldn't work in many cases because of the order: '%deod%cucumb%' works for 'Deodorant with a cucumber flavor', but if the search string is 'cucumb deod', the corresponding like statement is '%cucumb%deod%' and that doesn't match your example.